# Error Generic Method in java

Tags: java

```
package com.openwaf.test.basic;
public class MethodArgumentTest {
    static interface Inf{}
    static class One<E extends Inf > implements Inf{
        public <T extends One> T get(T k){
            return k;
        }
    }
    static class Two<E extends Inf> extends One<E>{ }
    public static void test(){
        One o=new One<Inf>();
        Two t=new Two<One>();
        o.<Two>get(t);
    }
}
```

Above code is just for testing purpose. IMHO it should compile without any problem ,but java compiler says

> MethodArgumentTest.java:15:
>   get(com.openwaf.test.basic.MethodArgumentTest.One) in
>   com.openwaf.test.basic.MethodArgumentTest.One cannot be applied to
>   (com.openwaf.test.basic.MethodArgumentTest.Two)
>
> o.get(t);
>
> 1 error

Can someone please help me out here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as you said this is for testing only I will not ask what this code is good for. The following one compiles but still produces a warning. You were not consequent enough defining the generics:

```
public class MethodArgumentTest {
    static interface Inf {
    }

    static class One<E extends Inf> implements Inf {
        public <T extends One<E>> T get(T k) {
            return k;
        }
    }

    static class Two<E extends Inf> extends One<E> {
    }

    public static void test() {
        One<Inf> o = new One<Inf>();
        Two<One<Inf>> t = new Two<One<Inf>>();

        o.<Two> get(t); /* unchecked warning */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... Problem was in line One<Inf> o = new One<Inf>(); now digging down how compiler handles this  .. anyways this problem is now solved .. Thanks again .. :)

Comment: No prob, it was an interesting exercise :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is

```
Two tPrime= o.get(t);
```

Comment: doesn't work .. as i can see and compiler says the same .. incompatible types
found   : com.openwaf.test.basic.MethodArgumentTest.One
required: com.openwaf.test.basic.MethodArgumentTest.Two
        Two tPrime= o.get(t);